# is all <giggily> about everything

Tags: vocabulary

I was wondering about the meaning of giggily. Could it be a typo. Even so, what does it mean as used in the definition below? I have looked it up to no avail, and subbing it with giggly does not make sense to me.

> **woo-la**
>
> The point at when a person is up in the middle of the night and cannot
>   think right/**is all giggily about everything**.
>   *Yeah..we were sitting up about 3am..I don't remember what she said because I was all woo-la*

http://www.diclib.com/woo-la/show/en/amslang/W/465/360/0/0/11175#ixzz4CY9vGVWb

Comment: Maybe [*giddy*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=giddy)? The example isn't really helpful. Any others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's based on  your normal [giggly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/giggly) (Oxford dictionary)

> Having a tendency to laugh in an excited, nervous, or silly way

*All giggly* here means being so giggly that it's difficult to stop  being giggly, due to being extremely tired.

*All giggly about everything* means laughing or giggling at (just about) anything being said.

I've never heard of *woo-la*, but someone who is *all giggly about everything* can be said to be temporarily in [la-la land](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/la-la+land), although they are not the only people who can be said to be there.

Comment: 'Giggly' is in standard dictionaries, and returns about 414,000 results on a Google search. 'Giggily' is in the Urban Dictionary (for what that's worth) (so is 'giggly'), and returns about 6,970 results.

Comment: **Learner** embeds the word in the phrase, *All giggly about everything*, whose meaning  was not intuitively obvious to him/her.